# apache 2.4 custom error respononses not working

Tags: apache, bitnami

I am trying to setup a custom 404 error not found page for my website. I've seen a lot of tutorials and read the docs here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html .

when I give an invalid url to my domain this is the default 404 page I get.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /notreal was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

this what I have in my httpd.conf file that allows the override:

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

I have the .htaccess file in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs` along with `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/error` that has the custom 404.html page I want outputted with custom JS and CSS.

EDIT:

Bitnami config file :

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Instead of creating a new Directory block and override it, can you edit the default virtual hosts we create in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file? You can find there other "ErrorDocument" directives. Please note that you will need to restart Apache after that `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Comment: I did as you suggested,I added the ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html into the bitnami.conf for both port 80 and port 443 still did not redirect to the page. I also deleted the htaccess file from my server and re-attempted. still no luck. I edited the question to demonstrate my entire bitnami conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my page 404 to work. so I read in the docs and it said that the page needed to be in the root directory. `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`.

It can be there, but for my problem i had a folder that points towards the domain. 
example.com

and in that folder `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domain` , you need to place your `/error` documents and `.htaccess` file.